# Python - Oracle - cx_Oracle - не видит схему

Tags: python, база-данных, oracle, cx-oracle

Пытаюсь подключиться к Oracle с помощью cx_oracle, коннект проходит.
Через pony ORM и SQLalchemy - проблема такая же.
Из гугла советы с current_schema не помогают...

[image: проблема]

[image: Не видит схему, а коннект проходит]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.
То есть замените скриншоты на текст, отформатируйте его.

Comment: Сайт не позволяет вставить код - ругается.

Comment: Тогда имеем очень очень большую вероятность остаться без ответа... даже не правильного.

Comment: _Сайт не позволяет вставить код - ругается_, а какое сообщение вы получаете - "Даже не вздумайте код текстом добавить!"? Что-то слабо верится. Может вы его  не форматируете?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code